# NameError: name 'ForeignKeyConstraint' is not defined

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a composite constraint with SQLAlchemy and I can't figure out what is going on:

```
class City(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'cities'
__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('city', 'state', name="unique_city"),)

city = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
state = db.Column(db.String(120), primary_key=True)
venue = db.relationship('Venue', backref='city', lazy=True)

class Venue(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'venue'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String)
address = db.Column(db.String(120))
city = db.Column(db.String(120))
state = db.Column(db.String(120))
phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
venue_genre = db.relationship('VenueGenre', backref='venue', lazy=True)
show = db.relationship('Show', backref='venue', lazy=True)

__table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint(
    [city, state],
    [city.city, city.state]),
)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
NameError: name 'ForeignKeyConstraint' is not defined
```

This is indented properly in python, not sure how to do that here. I feel like it's an easy fix, but I'm new to this and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Did you import it with something like `from sqlalchemy import ForeignKeyConstraint`

Comment: Either import it or access it through `db` like the other constructs.

Comment: Thank you, it work!